# Is it possible to get the FF14 free version on steam?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I was looking into getting the free version of FF14, just to try it out, but it doesn't seem to be available on Steam.

I'd love it on steam, since my whole PC catalog is already in there, and steam would keep it updated and all that, so... is there a way to get the free version via Steam, or am I stuck to download it from SquareEnix official website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the free version of Final Fantasy XIV is available on Steam. It’s listed as a demo.

https://store.steampowered.com/app/312060/FINAL_FANTASY_XIV_Online_Free_Trial/

> This is a free trial version of the game that will allow you to play free as your favorite FINAL FANTASY class up to level 60.
> If you wish to continue beyond level 60, please purchase the full version of the game on Steam. Several game features are restricted for the Free Trial.

Keep in mind, if you create your FFXIV account on Steam, it cannot be used with the standalone version of FFXIV. If you want to upgrade your account to the full game, you will need to buy your subscription through Steam.

Comment: Oh damn its way down the list in the demos thats why!